# Cell Contains String in another Worksheet Return True

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to return true in column B if any of the text in column A is present in worksheet2(Themes by Subcategory)column D  and return nothing if it is not present. I tried this so far `=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$65535,1,FALSE)), "", "True")` and don't know what' to do next.

- If "New Variables Needed" column A (for example: $data.tv.model) is present in "Themes by Subcategory" column D, then I want to return "True" in column B

  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19l-HxzuuLrzpwZ5fMVLwJKzYwSyYig3LRWoXfVV_8qM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: use this formula =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$65535,0)), "True", "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
   =if(isnumber(MATCH("*"&A3&"*",'Themes by subcategory'!D:D,0)),true,false)
```

Comment: How do I set it to return an empty value if its false?

Comment: I figured it out Thank you